# How do I calculate the number of X(an event happening) per the amount of something?

Tags: statistics

I am trying to calculate the number (X) of matches of sensitive data(M) found per amount of data scanned (D).
I am unsure of what equation to use for this though.

Example:
What is the amount of matches found per GB scanned given:

Total number of matches found = 702,400

Total amount of data scanned in bytes = 1,702,657,258,522

The amount of data scanned in GB will be = 1702.657259522

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching $X(D)$, you need to find the link between $X$ and $D$ first. As they only give you 3 numbers (2 to understand the pattern, 1 to apply the pattern), I suppose there is a linear relation between the matches and the data:
$$X \propto D \Rightarrow X = mD \ | \ m \in \mathbb{R}$$
In that case, you find $m$ with the global matches and the global data ($m = X_{total}/D_{total}$) and if you have the same linear pattern in GB, your answer should be: $$X_{GB} = mD_{GB} = \frac{X_{total}}{D_{total}}D_{GB}$$ However, there are some things I do not understand in your question, such as:

1. What does $M$ represents ?
2. Why is the number of data in GB not an integer while the total amout is one ?

I hope my answer will help you, but I'm not sure I understood the problem.

Comment: I was just using the M and D as variables to represent each value that would be placed there later, example M = number of matches found in total amount of data scanned. Sorry I wasn't very clear about that part. To answer your second question, the number in GB is a decimal due to the conversion of bytes to GB ( 1 GB = 1e+9 bytes ).

Comment: Ok, sorry I thought in the first place that "GB" meant "Great-Britain", and that you were compairing the global amount of data with the amount of data in Great-Britain ^^